# Accessing Data from Archive / Repository (FTP?)

Tags: matlab, ftp

I'm trying to write a script in MATLAB to pull down the data from this website: https://data.cresis.ku.edu/data/rds/2010_Antarctica_DC8/CSARP_standard/20101120_03/

which includes the accessing of subsequent ".mat" files present.

I'm not super familiar with data acquisition and I'm not sure if this is FTP or whatnot.

Question statement:

How do you conclude what type of protocol to access the data, and in what syntax is this accomplished in MATLAB?

I've begun to experiment with the method found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftp.mget.html

Comment: The protocol is HTTP over SSL/TLS ("HTTPS") as evidenced by the URL you gave - it starts with `https://`

Comment: Ah, sometimes it's the simplest things when you begin. I appreciate it.

I ended up using : 

wget -r -np https://data.cresis.ku.edu/data/rds/2010_Antarctica_DC8/CSARP_standard/20101120_03/

to download all of them.

Comment: If you figure out how to do it in MATLAB, remember to post an answer to your own question.  That helps others who are trying to solve the same problem.  (Unfortunately, I don't know anything about MATLAB's facilities for external network access, so I can't really answer.)